# Linear Algebra Involving nonsingular matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

$A^2+A+I=0$, show that $A$ is non-singular and $A^{-1}=A^2$.
Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Rearrange: $I=-A^2-A=A(-A-I)$. Can you conclude that $A$ is invertible? What is the inverse and how can it be written differently using the original identity?

Answer (score 4):

Next time, please tell us what you have tried to solve the problem. Here is a hint:
$$A^3-I=(A-I)(A^2+A+I)=0.$$

Comment: how'd you get a^3, sorry if its a dumb question

Comment: Break the brackets $(A-I)(A^2+A+I)=A(A^2+A+I)-(A^2+A+I)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\lambda,x)$ be an eigenpair of $A\implies \lambda\in\{\omega,\omega^2\}$ where $\omega,\omega^2$ are the complex cubic roots of unity. Since $\lambda\ne 0$, $A$ is nonsingular and hence, from the given equation, $A^{-1}(A^2+A+I)=0\implies A^{-1}=-(I+A)=A^2$